# What kind of tools are used in today's era to carve stones or large rocks in masonry?

Tags: masonry

I've always been curious as to how builders are able to shape things like granite or other stone slabs into the desired round-over or other type of support.
I've had some experience with clay as in ceramics, and those substances are malleable before they are air-dried and or fired.

For example, I went to tour a newly built church. In the middle of the vestibule there was a large baptismal font with the outside very rugged and the inside neatly made and smooth.

Comment: Yes, that fascinates me too. I’ve visited European churches with stone carvings and I’m always amazed...in one church they displayed the tools , which were crude chisels about 12” long. I suppose too labor intensive now days. I hope someone answers your question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_jet_cutter

Comment: it probably all CNC these days, with contraptions that look somewhat like 3d printers.

Comment: Could I use this if I wanted to post this as my own answer? https://science.howstuffworks.com/environmental/energy/question553.htm

Comment: @dandavis What is CNC?

Comment: basically, a computerized machine tool. [some images](https://www.google.com/search?q=stone+cnc&tbm=isch) to get a good sense of what i'm talking about. Many are water jets, some are saws, some are chisels, and some grind. There's no new magic process, just computerization of traditional techniques.

Comment: On site etching (house numbers, monuments, etc.) is generally done with a sandblaster and stencil now.